# Formatting Excel Sheet from Clipboard Paste

Tags: excel

In my clipboard, I have thousands of rows of data that can be easily formatted based on certain criteria. The data looks something like this:

```
1
Enabled
Allow Loopback
...
2
Enabled
...
```

When I paste into Excel, it doesn't let me choose a format, rather it just pastes it all into one column. There are 12 values between numbers (1,2,etc). I want to be able to create a table so that the 12 values are in one row, then the next 12 values are in the next row, and so on. How can this be accomplished?